# Is there any way to launch gui application without gui?

Tags: gui, x

I'm using Linux Mint MATE. I would like to launch a gui application without recognized by my eyes. I tried the following code which launches the application and moves it to another workspace with `wmctrl` right after the launch but that didn't work.

```
some_app_with_gui &
wmctrl -r title -t 1 #move window to another workspace (Say I'm in workspace 0 now)
```

As indicated [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1128091&p=7088804#post7088804), the reason is that `wmctrl` is executed before `some_app_with_gui`'s window appers. So the solution would be

```
some_app_with_gui &
sleep 0.8
wmctrl -r title -t 1 #move window to another workspace (Say I'm in workspace 0 now)
```

and this actually works.

With this solution, however, the window is recognized by my eyes for a moment (0.1 seconds or so). This is truly annoying and I'd like to avoid it.

Are there any solutions? It doesn't necessarily have to use `wmctrl`. Any other commands will be ok. And please note I don't access the window, i.e. the application is launched by a script and closed by the scripts, so completely hiding the window is ok.

---

How this question is different from ones with similar titles is

- that only one machine is involved (not SSH-related)
- and that I would like to launch gui application **on a machine with a desktop environment** without gui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a *virtual framebuffer X server*, `Xvfb`.

For example:

```
Xvfb :99 &
DISPLAY=:99 some_app_with_gui &
```

This runs the application on an entirely virtual X display, which has no visible presence on any physical display at all.

`Xvfb` is typically a separate package, so you might need to use your distribution's package manager to install it before using it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked really well on Linux Mint Mate 19 after `sudo apt install xvfb`.

Comment:  This will fail if the display isn't ready yet.

Answer (score 1):

For that I personally use a tool of my own, called [**unwin**](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/unwin).

It's like **telcoM answer**, but **automating** when to wait for and close xvfb.

If xvfb isn't **ready**, it will wait for it. And once there are no programs **running** on the frame-buffer, xvfb is closed automatically.

Comment: please add a one-liner of code that demonstrates how to use unwin

Comment: It's simply: `unwin [program]`